# Illustrator CC Save For Web Exported Artboards have a hyphen "-" when there is a space in the file name

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-management

I'm working with character animations and it happens that I need to replace an existing image with exact same name.

**Example:**

- Arm R
- Leg R
- Face A
- Face B
- etc
- .. ..

I edit those inside Illustrator. Then I want replace *Arm R* with the new edited *Arm R*. However when I save & export, Illustrator exports like this *"Arm-R"*. So the original image is not replaced instead I have 2 images now.

One called **Arm R**, other called **Arm-R**. I did not put a hyphen myelf.

It's a time killer to remove all the hyphens later from the name.

**How to prevent Illustrator to put a hyphen into a file name?**

Comment: Where I come from we Never put a space in a file name. I prefer an underscore. camelCase works too. Illustrator puts the hyphen to prevent the file name from having a space. That used to break some old machines, like me.

Comment: Spaces in file names can wreak havoc in web server environments. You should not use spaces in filenames if the file is going to be on a web server. If the file is not going be on web server, you possibly should not be using Save for Web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respectfully, you have it the "wrong way round" and in this instance, for a variety of reasons Illustrator is right, and you are wrong.

I find myself using underscores as spaces in *every filename I ever make*, psd's, .ai files...everything. You simply never know where a file might end up (like a web-server, or backed up to a NAS where you might want to perform bulk, command-line, operations on it). - *Spaces cause ambiguity*.

You would not want to delete your current file names from a web-server via:

```
rm Face A
```

...which would delete all the files called "Face", and all the files called "A" but you would not delete the file you intended. Non intended outcomes on web-servers (or backup machines) are scary!

Likewise is URLS you would face problems if you ever tried to download:

```
www.example.com/face a.txt
```

Also of course you have just run into an instance where an application is making the right choice... saving a file *for the web* should certainly avoid spaces, and you are having to carry out additional work to make the situation worse. This in itself should deter you.

I recommend you get a decent, free, file-renamer, like [Bulk Renamer](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) and that you put all those hyphens *back* (or go pro...with the underscore haha) and then abandon all thoughts of spaces from henceforth! You_will_not_regret_it!

Comment: Then_no_more_space_in_file_names. Thanks_for_the_detailed_info :D

Comment: haha my_pleasure